# How to slow down AnimateScrollToItem in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have a lazy list that I am animating scroll to Item when clicking on a button.

```
onClick = {
  scope.launch  {
    lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(selectedIndex)
  }
}
```

Why is it that the animateScrollToItem is SO fast? Can I slow it down a little? I am not seeing anywhere I can add a animationSpec, and with animateScrollBy() I would need to pass in a float rather than an index - which I do not want.

Answer (score 6):

That's the only possible way for now. `animateScrollBy()` is not that bad by the way, all you need is to know the size of the lazy container item.

```
val itemSize = 50.dp
val density = LocalDensity.current
val itemSizePx = with(density) { itemSize.toPx() }
val itemsScrollCount = 150
coroutineScope.launch {
   lazyListState.animateScrollBy(
     value = itemSizePx * itemsScrollCount
     animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 5000)
   )
}
```

Comment: How to calculate if the items are of different sizes? I think this complicates the use of animateScrollBy a lot. Google should expose Animation Spec in animateScrollToItem().