# Slow down the speed of scroll in compose in animateScrollToItem in lazylistscope in compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to slow down the speed of scroll in liststate.animateScrollToItem(position), however, the scroll is really fast. Is there a way to slow down the speed of scroll.

I tried adding delay(1000), before the animation but still the scroll is really fast.`

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight()),
state = listState) { // lazy list scope
 coroutineScope.launch {
delay(1000)
listState.scrollToItem(position)
        }`
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can achieve this using 'animateScrollBy' just like the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73137520/how-to-slow-down-animatescrolltoitem-in-jetpack-compose.  The method involves calculating the list size by multiplying itemSizePx by itemsCount and scrolling by the resulting size. If you have varying sizes for each item or need to use it differently, you can obtain the LazyLayout size by using Modifier.onSizeChanged { ... } and convert it to pixels (Px) using LocalDensity, similar to what was demonstrated in the mentioned example.